# Elasticsearch Update API if a field does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch

The example for upsert is:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.counter += count",
    "params" : {
        "count" : 4
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "counter" : 1
    }
}'
```

which works if the document does not exist previously.

Say i want to update a field that does not necessarily exist, but the document exists.
For example, the document might not have a counter field yet.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the update script to check if field exists:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "if( ctx._source.containsKey(\"counter\") ){ ctx._source.counter += count; } else { ctx._source.counter = 1; }",
    "params" : {
        "count" : 4
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "counter" : 1
    }
}'
```

Comment: Great! Do you happen to know if there's some site that would actually explain the MVEL language? I tried my best to learn it, but can't find any decent resource.
http://mvel.codehaus.org/Language+Guide+for+2.0 is horrible and covers next to nothing

Comment: That's the best resource that I am aware of. My advise would be to install [javascript plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-lang-javascript) and switch to javascript as your scripting language.

Comment: From elasticsearch documentation about scripting language: 
`The scripting module uses by default groovy (previously mvel in 1.3.x and earlier)`